# Trying to use if else of getopts to pass an argument from the terminal and capture that information in a log

Tags: linux, shell-script, getopts

I am trying to pass an argument from a command string in the terminal. I am modifying a script to detect that command and allow the user to see what the script is doing.

This is what I am trying to detect.

```
[root@linuxtest] ./testscript.sh $1 -v
```

This command is to verbose what the script is doing to the terminal as well as log this to to a log file. Now, depending on the user, this script would either detect the commands a user has entered:

```
sh testscript.sh $1 -v
```

or

```
./teshscript.sh -v
```

Now, within the script there is already a command:

exec 1> {LOG} 2>&1

This allows the echos to be logged into the file. However, this will not show up in the terminal, but be logged into the text file of whatever path that {LOG} file is stored. What I have right now is this:

```
name=`sh testscipt.sh $1 -v`

if [[ -n "$name" ]]; then
   2>&1 2>&- | tee -a ${LOG}
else
   1> {LOG} 2>&1
fi
```

But I am not too sure what the logic should be when to have this be setup. I have researched "getops" to allow a case, but I am not too sure what the syntax for this. So, in essence, I am trying allow the user to run this, but when they want to view this they would have to input the commands as stated to view the echos in the terminal.

What is the proper way to do this either using getops/case for the switch, and pass arguments to be detected when a user enters in the commands?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Are you saying that when you add `-v` as an argument to your script, you want to turn on verbose (`set -o verbose` or `set -v`) during the execution of `testscript.sh`?

Comment: It is designed for automation, however, this pass of the argument, is only used when a user inputs information. '$1' is used to enter in linux accounts for a script that pulls credentials from a database. The script is being used by to automation other servers, and when needed users can enter in the name of the account, which is the first ($1) argument. The '-v' is the switch to verbose the echos to the terminal, so that the user can enter in their own Linux account. The problem I am having is trying to translate that into bash script.

Comment: The idea is the verbose only when a user is using the script. When it is not in use it will just use the normal automated version of the script. I was thinking of 'getops' and case values to figure it out, but have not been successful in trying to get that into a script. The 'if-else' statements seem to be the easier to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Redirections and pipes are not part of a command; they are the structure of the pipeline *between* commands.  As such, you won't be able to look for a parameter that redirects standard output or standard error by looking at command line arguments.

You can, however, look at `/proc/$$/fd` and see to which `0` (standard input), `1` (standard output), and `2` (standard error) are linked.

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "My pid is $$"
ls -l /proc/$$/fd/
$ ./foo.sh 2> /tmp/errorsgohere
My pid is 30842
total 0
lrwx------ 1 username username 64 Jun 28 14:33 0 -> /dev/pts/0
lrwx------ 1 username username 64 Jun 28 14:33 1 -> /dev/pts/0
l-wx------ 1 username username 64 Jun 28 14:33 2 -> /tmp/errorsgohere
lr-x------ 1 username username 64 Jun 28 14:33 255 -> /home/username/foo.sh
```